# native-run ios: Unable to get app bundle identifier at Object.getBundleId

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I'm using Ionic v4 and I would like to emulate the project. I got an error.

**Command**

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --verbose
```

**Error**

> native-run ios --app "platforms/ios/build/emulator/Testapp.app" --verbose
>   2019-06-05T23:34:54.962Z native-run Caught fatal error: { Error: Unable to get app bundle identifier
>       at Object.getBundleId (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/native-run/dist/ios/utils/app.js:21:11) code: undefined, exitCode: 1, data: undefined }
>   ERR_UNKNOWN: Unable to get app bundle identifier

**I tried**

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Any tips about how to solve the error ?